# Can a C# method chain be "too long"?

Tags: c#, method-chaining

Not in terms of readability, naturally, since you can always arrange the separate methods into separate lines. Rather, is it dangerous, for any reason, to chain an excessively large number of methods together? I use method chaining primarily to save space on declaring individual one-use variables, and traditionally using return methods instead of methods that modify the caller. Except for string methods, those I kinda chain mercilessly. In any case, I worry sometimes about the impact of using exceptionally long method chains all in one line.

Let's say I need to update the value of one item based on someone's username. Unfortunately, the shortest method to retrieve the correct user looks something like the following.

```
SPWeb web = GetWorkflowWeb();
SPList list2 = web.Lists["Wars"];
SPListItem item2 = list2.GetItemById(3);
SPListItem item3 = item2.GetItemFromLookup("Armies", "Allied Army");
SPUser user2 = item2.GetSPUser("Commander");
SPUser user3 = user2.GetAssociate("Spouse");
string username2 = user3.Name;
item1["Contact"] = username2;
```

Everything with a 2 or 3 lasts for only one call, so I might condense it as the following (which also lets me get rid of a would-be-superfluous 1):

```
SPWeb web = GetWorkflowWeb();
item["Contact"] = web.Lists["Armies"]
                     .GetItemById(3)
                     .GetItemFromLookup("Armies", "Allied Army")
                     .GetSPUser("Commander")
                     .GetAssociate("Spouse")
                     .Name;
```

Admittedly, it looks a lot longer when it is all in one line and when you have `int.Parse(ddlArmy.SelectedValue.CutBefore(";#", false))` instead of `3`. Nevertheless, this is one of the average lengths of these chains, and I can easily foresee some of exceptionally longer counts. Excluding readability, is there anything I should be worried about for these 10+ method chains? Or is there no harm in using really really long method chains?

Comment: Ten is nothing. If you had over, say, ten thousand, then you might start running into problems. You said that you do this to "save space". I do not understand what space it is you believe you are saving, or why you believe that space to be a scarce resource which requires careful sheparding. Can you explain what empirical evidence supports your belief that you are saving on use of a scarce or expensive resource?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I believe your second example is much more readable. If I was tasked with maintaining that example, I'd much more quickly understand what the second was doing. There is much less superfluous code. I imagine readability should be the main concern here. If your chains are easier to read then that is a good thing

Comment: @Eric I haven't claimed anything to be a scarce or expensive resource. The space I'm saving is a couple lousy bytes of filespace in the code file to state ";\r\nCLASS bar = foo" between the chained methods, which in turn looks cleaner to me. Considering that it looking clean to me is a matter of readability and I *explicitly exclude readability as a concern*, where are you getting that I find this space to "require careful shepherding"?

Comment: @Jeremy Ironically, I arranged that second example for readability only on this website. Based on what property is actually being assigned by the chain-return, I can usually tell what the entire chain is without actually scrolling through it when I list it in one line.

Comment: I get concerned when someone's primary engineering concern is optimizing utilization of a resource that is unimportant. That seems like a bad engineering practice, which is why I called it out. If your primary concern is in fact not making the code *small* but rather making the code *more readable* (which is reasonable, though I personally would concentrate on *correctness* before readability) then why emphasize the size aspect in your question? Your question, as I understand it now, is basically "I find this technique more readable; are there hidden technical costs?" No, there are not.

Comment: @Eric I'm not concerned about optimization at all. I am in fact emphasizing correctness: I want to know if there are actual problems (incorrectness in functionality, as it were) associated with really long method chains. The immediate example I had from my code is only 6 methods long, which I expect is trivial in number, so I wanted to emphasize that the question is "Is there such thing as too long?" and not "Is my 6-method chain too long?"

Comment: While the second form looks prettier, I find the first to be crazy easier to debug.  Using "var" can make it a little easier on the eyes, though.  If something breaks in step three, pretty isn't getting me anywhere.  I go into fits when I am trying to debug things like: return Method1(Method2(Method3(my_value.Method4())));

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**There are no technical limitations on how long a method chain can be.**

However, three areas that can become problemattic are **debugging**, **exception handling**, and **resource disposal**.

Debugging is complicated by the same fact that makes chaining so elegant - the lack of intermediate temporary variables. Unfortunately, without temp variables, inspecting intermediate results when debugging becomes painful.

Exception handling is complicated by the fact that you cannot isolate exceptions raised from one method vs. another. Normally this isn't an issue if you can't do something meaningful in response to the exception - just let it propagate up the call chain. However, if you do realize at a later point that you need exception handling, you have to refactor the chaining syntax to be able to insert appropriate try/catch handlers.

Similar to exception handling is the case of deterministic disposal of resources. The easiest way in C# to accomplish this is with `using()` - unfortunately, chaining syntax precludes that. If you are calling methods that return disposable objects, it probably a good idea to avoid chaining syntax so that you can be a good "code citizen" and dispose of those resources as early as possible.

Method chaining syntax is often a used in [fluent APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), where it allows the syntax of your code to more closely reflect the sequence of operations you intend. LINQ is one example in .NET where fluent/chaining syntax is often seen.

Comment: agreed, i was just about posting the same

Comment: There are technical limitations arising from tooling. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67034345/64334

Answer (score 7):

Readability is the biggest concern, but often that isn't a problem at all.

You could also describe LINQ query syntax as (underneath it all) *exactly* such a setup. It just makes it look prettier ;-p

One *possible* issue is where you need to introduce things like `using` or `lock`; with the fluent API you may be tempted to simply drop these components, but that might lead to oddities when an exception is thrown.

The other possible thought is that you might want to have more granular exception handling around some of the calls; but you can always just break the flow:

```
var foo = bar.MethodA().MethodB(...).MethodC();
try {
    foo.MethodD();
} catch (SomeSpecificException) {
    //something interesting
}
```

Or you could even do *that* in an extension method to keep the fluent appearance:

```
bar.MethodA().MethodB(...).MethodC().MyExtensionMethodD();
```

where `MyExtensionMethodD` is the one you add with special handling (exceptions, locks, using, etc).

Answer (score 6):

This is considered a code smell by some and not by others.  Anytime you see the following:

```
Foo.getBar().getBlah().getItem().getName();
```

you should really be thinking, "what do I really want?"  Instead perhaps your method should contain a function call:

```
String getName(Int _id, String _item)
{
    return myBar.getName( _id, _item );
}
```

which then delegates downward, amongst the classes.  Then, if something changes in one of your classes at a later update, you'll see exactly where it occurs and can change it in one location.

Answer (score 4):

The only consern you should consider regarding this (if yor ignoring readability) is resource handling and GC.. Questions you should ask are.

- Are the calls I am making returning objects that should be disposed of?
- am I initing alot of stuff inside a single scope rather than smaller scopes that GC might be more reactive to? (GC is scheduled to run each time you leave a scope, though scheduling and when it actually runs are two different things :-p).

But really.. weather you call one method per line, or string them all togeather its all ends up being the same in IL (or very nearly the same).

Josh

Comment: The GC is not scheduled to run each time you leave a scope - it runs when there is no free space on the managed heap.

Comment: is that the case? I know when I was testing using distuctors to manage a pool of singletons (back about 3 years ago) the distructor was getting called when I left scope regardless of heap size (ie almost none)..  And I know the distructor is called (when present) by the first pass of GC..

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, there is a technical limitation you can encounter: very long method chains will cause the services that deliver intellisense to crash and subsequently their host processes (Linqpad 6, Visual Studio 2019, and probably others).

I discovered this when I converted a script that I use to track my personal work from a collection based API to a fluent API invocation chain. I found that the code I had would crash any IDE I put it in. Research led me to this long-standing github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9795

It's easy enough to break up really long chains into separate statements.