# Is it possible to call method directly on object literals in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, call, literals

In C#, when calling some instance methods, We always declare a variable of that type, then assign a value to it, and call that method at last:

```
string str = "this is a string";
int test = str.IndexOf("a");
```

In Javascript, we can do this:

```
var test = 'sdfsldkfjskdf'.indexOf('a');
```

Is this kind of method calls legal in C#, say, directly use the string literal as a shorthand, without the declaration of a variable?

Comment: Short answer is yes and you can also chain method calls:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849193/can-a-c-method-chain-be-too-long

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely valid and fine.

I suspect you *don't* always declare a variable even without using literals. For example, consider:

```
string x = "hello";
string y = x.Substring(2, 3).Trim();
```

Here we're using the result of `Substring` as the instance on which to call `Trim`. No separate variable is used.

But this could equally have been written:

```
string y = "hello".Substring(2, 3).Trim();
```

The same is true for primitive literals too:

```
string x = 12.ToString("0000");
```

Ultimately, a literal is just another kind of *expression*, which can be used as the target of calls to instance methods.

Comment: thx very much. But I'm just wondering: why the VS IntelliSense works on a string literal, but does not show anything when typing `10.`. Because it can not infer the actual type of 10 ?

Comment: @pink: Typing `10.` and then Ctrl-Space works for me. Without pressing Ctrl-Space, I suspect VS doesn't want to present the IntelliSense options as you may well be writing a floating point literal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. However I would not recommend it in general, because it is confusing, and not clear to other developers what you are doing.

Comment: IMO. There are cases when this sort of thing may be OK, but I struggle to find occasions when it it the right way to do something. Most of the time, I think it requires a second look. YMMV

Comment: One example I've used quite a few times: I want a static field of type `char[]`, and the easiest way to populate it is `"abcdef".ToCharArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's valid. No problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the best thing about it is that you **don't even have to check for null**.